# Can I call functions that take an array/pointer argument using a std::vector instead?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stl, vector

I want to rewrite some code that uses a lot of `unsigned char` arrays, to instead make use of `std::vector<unsigned char>` objects. The problem I have is that these are currently used to store the data that will be written to either a serial port or socket write buffer and the library functions to do this take either `void*` or `unsigned char*` . An example of such a function is

```
  WriteToSocketBuffer(unsigned char* pBuffer, int iSize);
```

so currently I have code of the form

```
 unsigned char* pArray = new unsigned char[iSize];
 //   populate array with data
 WriteToSocketBuffer(pArray,iSize);
 delete [] pArray;
```

My question is the following: If I change my class to have a `std::vector<unsigned char>` instead of a raw array can I simply call my library function using

```
  std::vector<unsigned char> myVector;
  WriteToSocketBuffer(&myVector[0],myVector.size());
```

Does passing the address of the first element in the vector act in the same was as passing in the address of the first element in a raw array. Is it this simple?

Comment: In C++11 you can also use std::array.

Comment: @DragoonWraith, how trying would help? Things like allowing non contiguous representation may break it in general and yet succeed in basic tests.

Comment: @DragoonWraith Rather than rewrite core functionality that will take a week and massively impact on my code internals, I thought I would ask the question first just to check that what I suspect will happen actually will happen.

Comment: Note that as-written this is undefined behavior, because `myVector` contains no elements. You want `std::vector<unsigned char> myVector(iSize);` instead.

Comment: @GManNickG Yes indeed, I omitted the populating of the vector. I was really just trying to convey the general idea. I should have inserted a commented code line for clarity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, The elements of a vector are assured to be contiguous similar to an array.

Reference:

**C++03 Standard:**    **[lib.vector] 23.2.4 Class template vector**

> ......
>   **The elements of a vector are stored contiguously**, meaning that if `v` is a `vector<T, Allocator>` where `T` is some type other than `bool`, then it obeys the identity `&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()`

Comment: I thought it would probably be OK but thanks for confirming it.

Answer (score 6):

C++98 didn't mandate contiguous allocation for the data in an `std::vector`, but that's what all known implementations did anyway.

As of C++03, that was standardized as a requirement, so it's now required, not just how things happen to be.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that, as long as the buffer is never empty.

If the vector is ever empty, then `&buffer[0]` is an error, and it will likely crash even though the called function wouldn't normally dereference the pointer because the size is 0.