# Is it safe to pass a pointer to the first element in a vector when an array is expected?

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I call functions that take an array/pointer argument using a std::vector instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058838/can-i-call-functions-that-take-an-array-pointer-argument-using-a-stdvector-ins)

I recently came across something like this:

```
class X {
    public: void foo(float* p, int elements);
};
```

= a method that expects an array of float values.

But in the example code this was the way they used it:

```
std::vector<float> bar;
bar.push_back(42);
// ...

X x;
x.foo( &bar[0], (int)bar.size() );
```

Now I'm wondering whether this is a safe method or just happens to work with most implementations of `std::vector`? (maybe this is an operator-overloading thing? I'm not yet that confident with this stuff..)

Comment: Take note that it has a `data()` function for this purpose now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it's safe.

n3337 23.3.6.1/1. In C++03 standard this is 23.2.4/1

> A vector is a sequence container that supports random access iterators. In addition, it supports (amortized)
> constant time insert and erase operations at the end; insert and erase in the middle take linear time. Storage
> management is handled automatically, though hints can be given to improve efficiency. **The elements of a
> vector are stored contiguously**, meaning that if v is a vector where T is some type other
> than bool, then it obeys the identity &v[n] == &v[0] + n for all 0 <= n < v.size().

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is allowable and will work as Forever points out. However, it is safe only for so long as you take care not to delete vector and leave a dangling pointer in the array. Since you are sharing memory between the array and the vector, it is up to you to manage that memory.

Answer (score -1):

from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/):

> As such, their elements are **ordered following a strict linear sequence**.

using that definition and the element access operator ([]), then expression `&avector[0]` gets the address of the first element, and the next elements are contiguous sequence after it.

Comment: Elements of any sequence container are "ordered following a strict linear sequence", but that doesn't mean they're stored in a contiguous array. The second paragraph of your link would be more relevant: "vector containers have their elements stored in **contiguous storage locations**".

Comment: Indeed, that also applies to `std::list`, where the elements are not contiguous.