# C++ reading text file by blocks

Tags: c++, text-files, ifstream

I really didn't find a satisfied answer at google and I/O in C++ is a little bit tricky. I would like to read text file by blocks into a vector if possible. Alas, I couldn't figure out how. I am not even sure, if my infinite loop will be break in all possibilities,  because I/O is tricky. So, the best way I was able to figure out is this:

```
char buffer[1025]; //let's say read by 1024 char block
buffer[1024] = '\0';
std::fstream fin("index.xml");
if (!fin) {
    std::cerr << "Unable to open file";        
} else {
    while (true) {          
        fin.read(buffer, 1024);
        std::cout << buffer;
        if (fin.eof())
            break;
    }

}
```

Please, note the second line with '\0'. Is it not odd? Can I do something better? Can I read the data into the vector instead of char array? Is it appropriate to read into vector directly?

Thanks for your answers.

PS. Reading by chunks have sense indeed. This code is short but I am storing it in cyclic buffer.

Comment: You mean that normal C I/O does not work for you in C++? `int fd = open("file", O_RDONLY); if (fd >=0) { for (ssize_t rd=0; (rd=read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0;) {do something;} close(fd); }`

Comment: I was told that is not recommended to C and C++ code if I have a choose

Comment: I'm guessing you want to _append_ to the vector, and not overwrite the contents in it every time in the loop?

Comment: BTW, `fstream` is derived for istream (and ostream) and supports `read(char_type *, streamsize)` (and `write(const char_type *, streamsize)`). So just `read` into the `buffer` and you're fine

Comment: @iwtu: you were told wrong, but it is of no matter here. Use of system calls is a fine C++ code :)

Comment: @fork0 That is no normal C I/O. C doesn't have neither an `open` nor a `read` nor a `close` function. You're using platform-dependent extensions for something that doesn't need any platform-specific code.

Comment: @ChristianRau: replace with fopen/fread. POSIX is a pretty common platform, though

Comment: @fork0 Yeah, Win32 also is, I wouldn't replace them with `ReadFile` though. It's just that it was rather misplaced after suggesting to use *"normal C I/O"*, because using platform-dependent C code (which isn't normal in any way) is never an option over platform-independent C++ code (or even standard C code for that matter) offering the exact same functionality for any C++ application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be fine doing the following

```
 vector<char> buffer (1024,0);      // create vector of 1024 chars with value 0   
 fin.read(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
```

The elements in a vector are guaranteed to be stored contiguously, so this should work - but you should ensure that the vector is never empty. I asked a similar question here recently - check the answers to that for specific details from the standard [Can I call functions that take an array/pointer argument using a std::vector instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058838/can-i-call-functions-that-take-an-array-pointer-argument-using-a-stdvector-ins)

Answer (score 0):

```
std::ifstream fin("index.xml");
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << fin.rdbuf();
std::string result = buffer.str();
```

Exactly what you need.

Comment: I don't see any block of data. I assume it reads whole input till the end.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I have encountered the same problem.  I use read and gcount founction to solve it. It works well. Here is the code.

```
vector<string> ReadFileByBlocks(const char* filename)
{
    vector<string> vecstr;

    ifstream fin(filename, ios_base::in);
    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        char* buffer = new char[1024];
        while (fin.read(buffer, 1024))
        {
            string s(buffer);
            vecstr.push_back(s);
        }

       // if the bytes of the block are less than 1024,
       // use fin.gcount() calculate the number, put the va
       // into var s
       string s(buffer, fin.gcount());
       vecstr.push_back(s);

       delete[] buffer;
       fin.close();
   }
   else
   {
        cerr << "Cannot open file:" << filename << endl;
   }

   return vecstr;
}
```